# Pandas dataframe reports no matching string when the string is present

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, search

Fairly new to python. This seems to be a really simple question but I can't find any information about it.
I have a list of strings, and for each string I want to check whether it is present in a dataframe (actually in a particular column of the dataframe. Not whether a substring is present, but the whole exact string.

So my dataframe is something like the following:

```
A=pd.DataFrame(["ancestry","time","history"])
```

I should simply be able to use the "string in dataframe" method, as in

```
"time" in A
```

This returns False however.
If I run

```
"time" == A.iloc[1]
```

it returns "True", but annoyingly as part of a series, and this depends on knowing where in the dataframe the corresponding string is.
Is there some way I can just use the string in df method, to easily find out whether the strings in my list are in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to deal with this is to compare the whole dataframe with `"time"`. That will return a mask where each value of the DF is True if it was `time`, False otherwise. Then, you can use `.any()` to check if there are any True values:

```
>>> A = pd.DataFrame(["ancestry","time","history"])
>>> A
          0
0  ancestry
1      time
2   history

>>> A == "time"  # or A.eq("time")
       0
0  False
1   True
2  False

>>> (A == "time").any()
0    True
dtype: bool
```

Notice in the above output, `(A == "time").any()` returns a Series where each entry is a column and whether or not that column contained `time`. If you want to check the *entire dataframe* (across all columns), call `.any()` twice:

```
>>> (A == "time").any().any()
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [`.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to the end:

```
'time' in A.to_numpy()
```

As you've noticed, the `x in pandas.DataFrame` syntax doesn't produce the result you want. But `.to_numpy()` transforms the dataframe into a Numpy array, and `x in numpy.array` works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `(myseries==mystr).any()` will do what you ask. The special `__contains__` method of DataFrames (which informs behavior of **`in`**) checks whether your string is a column of the DataFrame, e.g.

```
>>> A = pd.DataFrame({"c": [0,1,2], "d": [3,4,5]})
>>> 'c' in A
True
>>> 0 in A
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly modify your dataframe and use .str.contains for checking where the string is present in your series.

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['A']=pd.Series(["ancestry","time","history"])

df['A'].str.contains("time")
```